# Chunk size bigger than configured

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongodb-3.6

We have a sharded mongo cluster. We have configured the chunk size to be 256M but they are ~1.5G each. There are no jumbo chunks as our shard key is well balanced (we have also checked for them specifically). 
What can be the cause of having bigger than configured chunk sizes? And what can I do to auto split them?

EDIT

```
Shard Mongo at Mongo/
 data : 416.39GiB docs : 134529720 chunks : 368
 estimated data per chunk : 1.13GiB
 estimated docs per chunk : 365569

Shard db3repl at 
 data : 402.97GiB docs : 129491879 chunks : 372
 estimated data per chunk : 1.08GiB
 estimated docs per chunk : 348096

Shard db4repl at 
 data : 396.18GiB docs : 127334616 chunks : 368
 estimated data per chunk : 1.07GiB
 estimated docs per chunk : 346017

Shard db5repl at 
 data : 43.89GiB docs : 14141333 chunks : 368
 estimated data per chunk : 122.14MiB
 estimated docs per chunk : 38427
```

Comment: Are you really sure that automatic balancer is up and running?

Comment: @JJussi We have turned on and off but the number of chunks between shards are equal. Is it the balancer's responsibility to split the chunks?

Comment: Split is done by config server(s) and data is moved between shard nodes.

Comment: Have you checked what are (single) chunk min/max values? Can split be done? If there is no space, then split cannot be done. Check that split-script from my answer, comment away those lines "var tulos..." to print(c); and it will print out all you chunk boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

To split you can use something like this...

```
sh.stopBalancer();
var c=0;
db.chunks.find({ns:"database.collection", "shard" : "S0RS0"}).sort({$natural:1}).limit(1400).forEach(function(d)
{
  printjson(d.min);printjson(d.max);
  var tulos=db.adminCommand( { split: d.ns, bounds: [ d.min, d.max ] } );
  if (tulos.ok < 1) {
    print("Split ERROR");
    printjson(tulos);
  }
  print(c);
  c++;
})
sh.startBalancer();
```